# Onsen UI Toolbar title and icons are not vertically aligned in physical device

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, css, onsen-ui

I'm using onsen ui to build a phonegap mobile app. Toolbar line-height is set to the size of toolbar so that the inner elements are vertically centered and text-align to center. It is working perfectly fine in browser but not on a physical device.
**CSS**

```
.navigation-bar {
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 14px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
word-spacing: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font: inherit;
color: inherit;
background: transparent;
border: none;
line-height: normal;
cursor: default;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
z-index: 2;
display: block;
height: 44px;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
background: rgba(56,56,56,0.97);
color: #dbd8d8;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
font-weight: 400;
width: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: visible;
border-bottom: none;
}

ons-toolbar ~ .page__content {
top: 44px;
}

.navigation-bar__left {
max-width: 44%;
width: 27%;
text-align: left;
height: 100%;
line-height: 44px;

}

.navigation-bar__title {
height: 100%;
line-height: 44px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #dbd8d8;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: visible;
}

.navigation-bar__right {
max-width: 50%;
width: 27%;
text-align: right;
height: 100%;
line-height: 50px;
}
```

Here is screenshot of app in a physical device.
[image]

Comment: Please also post the CSS you're using. Did you change some fonts or the font sizes?

Comment: Ok, I've added the CSS.

Comment: Also, on what version of Android does this happen?

Comment: I've only tested it on a Lollipop device yet. In phonegap developer app and compiled apk. Both give the same results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is only specific to my LG G2 running Lollipop. Tested on two more devices, working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solve that using Flex:

```
.list__item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Don't forget to use "margin-right: 5px;" on icons if it is the case